# Configuring quagga to report Openvpn VPN subnet

Tags: linux, openvpn, ubuntu-12.04, quagga, rip

I'm trying to use quagga with RIP2 to route traffic through an openvpn server.

At the moment I'm having trouble because it's reporting the VPN subnet (`172.19.2.x`) as just a single IP (`172.19.2.1`).  I've clearly missed a step but I'm not finding anything obvious in the documentation to point out why this is happening.

My Draytek (2820) router reports it's routing table as:

```
Key: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, * - default, ~ - private
*            0.0.0.0/ 0.0.0.0          via 132.93.20.1      WAN2
C       132.93.20.0/ 255.255.254.0    directly connected    WAN2
C~      192.168.10.0/ 255.255.255.0    directly connected    LAN 
R~        172.19.2.1/ 255.255.255.255  via 192.168.10.10     LAN  (2/88050)
```

The zebra.conf configuration on the VPN server (`192.168.10.10`) is:

```
! -*- zebra -*-
hostname jupiter-zebra
password [removed]
enable password [removed]

! Tried adding this but didn't help
! ip route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 eth0
! ip route 172.19.2.0   255.255.255.0 tun0

log file /var/log/quagga/zebra.log
```

The ripd.conf configuration on the VPN server is:

```
hostname jupiter-rip2
password [removed]

router rip
 network 192.168.10.0/24
 network 172.19.2.0/24
log file /var/log/quagga/ripd.log
```

Is there anything I've clearly missed to get my VPN server to report it's VPN subnet (`172.19.2.x`) instead of only it's VPN ip (`172.19.2.1`)?

Comment: Okay the issue here is with OpenVPN. I'll be posting an answer once I've got everything sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should allow ospf to redistribute kernel routes:

[OSPF: how to advertise the subnet of an OpenVPN server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/281535/ospf-how-to-advertise-the-subnet-of-an-openvpn-server)

Example:

`router ospf
  ospf router-id 10.0.6.1
  redistribute connected
  redistribute kernel
  network 10.0.4.0/24 area 0.0.0.0`